# Opacity change on scroll affects div over top

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get a image to fade on scroll down the page and have used js to do it, but it's having a weird effect on a div that's over the top of the image (negative margin).

This is the page: http://wwwjoneshall.wpengine.com/project/west-hollywood-library/

To see it, you have to look on a large screen because it sort of pops just as you start to scroll and goes quite transparent. The grey div over the top isn't supposed to change opacity.

This is the js for the fade of the image banner:

```
var fadeStart=100
    ,fadeUntil=600
    ,fading = jQuery('.project-banner')
;

jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    var offset = jQuery(document).scrollTop()
        ,opacity=0
    ;
    if( offset<=fadeStart ){
        opacity=1;
    }else if( offset<=fadeUntil ){
        opacity=1-offset/fadeUntil;
    }
    fading.css('opacity',opacity);
});
```

CSS

```
.grey-overlay {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    z-index: 9999;
    margin: -130px 3% 0 3%;
}
.project-banner {
    height: 1015px;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
```

}

Any thoughts on what's causing this issue? Obviously I can fix it by moving the div off the image, but the designer is keen to have it look this way.

Comment: You're making the container opaque, this is also going to effect all children of the wrapping element.

Comment: Try to change background-color in your js, and use rgba, that way, it will only affect targeted element, not the children something like background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);

Comment: But it's not a child element, it's a separate div underneath it. I have just moved it over with negative top margin.

Answer (score 1):

to use z-index; you need to reset position also (any value but static)

> https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index

```
.grey-overlay {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
position:relative;/* here z-index comes avalaible */
    z-index: 9999;
    margin: -130px 3% 0 3%;
}
```